# Query the most recent entries in a collection in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

This mongodb query below returns the most recent entries to a collection

```
db.RSS.find().limit(6).sort({$natural:-1}).pretty()
```

Does anyone know how to implement this query in Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Mongo-Java Driver, this code is an example:

```java
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase("test");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("RSS");
FindIterable<Document>  it = collection.find().limit(6).sort(new Document().append("$natural", -1));
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = it.iterator();
while(cursor.hasNext()){
    Document doc = cursor.next();
    System.out.println(doc.toJson());
}
```